# Using flex, how can order content differently on desktop vs mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When my site is in mobile, it will display as it is in the snippet below. But, when it's in desktop I want it to display as you see in the image below (min-width: 1400px).

There's a **[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/ZEKgKje)** if you'd prefer.

```css
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove default margin */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
figure,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #005fec;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    line-height: 4.25rem;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    line-height: 2.75rem;
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

main.case-study section .details {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  main.case-study section .details {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  main.case-study section .details {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 768px;
  }
}
main.case-study section .details__top {
  background: #EBEFF5;
  padding: 2.25rem 1.25rem;
  margin: 0 0 3rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}
main.case-study section .details__title {
  font-weight: 900;
}
main.case-study section .details__detail .kicker {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
main.case-study section .details__detail h6 span:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 900;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:not(:first-child),
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:not(:last-child) {
  background-image: url("../../../../assets/svg/bullet.svg");
  background-position: 0 0.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sub-head {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sub-head {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="case-study">
  <section>
    <div class="details__top">
      <div class="details">
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6 class="kicker kicker--bold">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
          </h6>
          <h6>
            <span>Plan:</span>
            <span> <a href="#">Professional</a></span>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6>
            <span>Users:</span>
            <span>23</span>
          </h6>
          <h6>
            <span>Founded:</span>
            <span>2017</span>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6>
            <span>Favorite Features:</span>
            <span>
              <a href="#">SMS</a>,
              <a href="#">Amazing Service</a>,
              <a href="#">Call Flows w/ Auto Attendants</a>,
              <a href="#">Auto-Attendant</a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
    <section>
      <div class="details">
        <h4 class="sub-head">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A laudantium amet id? Harum eius magni iure veniam architecto expedita, commodi quidem ut voluptatem laborum sint? Possimus reprehenderit ullam tempora distinctio ea quos nisi aliquid, soluta dicta repellat ipsam velit officia doloribus, labore odio quis sit dolorum quibusdam earum. Iste unde voluptatibus ad necessitatibus quia recusandae voluptas asperiores quam, tempora ipsam?
        </h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, dolore omnis inventore laborum in sequi adipisci a alias nesciunt aliquid? Perferendis voluptates ipsa dicta fugiat!</p>
        
        <p>Cupiditate quam nisi non corrupti debitis fugiat excepturi? Perferendis, id dolor? Maxime molestiae voluptatibus ad, porro quidem sapiente pariatur cupiditate accusamus officia rem iste perspiciatis.</p>
        
        <p>Iusto, amet? Est eos, ducimus nostrum commodi, voluptate, ullam vero laboriosam dolores quisquam error sed exercitationem perspiciatis quia non soluta a facere mollitia quasi cumque?</p>
        
        <p>Cumque dolor doloribus obcaecati atque voluptatem temporibus eius sapiente, dolorum reprehenderit? Ea recusandae consequuntur similique quod hic? Id rerum architecto magni qui quis ratione totam.</p>
      </div>
    </section>  
</main>
```

**What approach should I take to get this result?**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While it's certainly possible to do this with flexbox's [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) property, I would just stick with a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) that applies `display:flex` to the `.case-study` element when the screen's width is smaller than 1400px.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  main.case-study{
    display:flex;
  }
}

/* ================ */


/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove default margin */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
figure,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #005fec;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    line-height: 4.25rem;
  }
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    line-height: 2.75rem;
  }
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h5 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
  }
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

main.case-study section .details {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  main.case-study section .details {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  main.case-study section .details {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 768px;
  }
}
main.case-study section .details__top {
  background: #EBEFF5;
  padding: 2.25rem 1.25rem;
  margin: 0 0 3rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}
main.case-study section .details__title {
  font-weight: 900;
}
main.case-study section .details__detail .kicker {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
main.case-study section .details__detail h6 span:first-of-type {
  font-weight: 900;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:not(:first-child),
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:not(:last-child) {
  background-image: url("../../../../assets/svg/bullet.svg");
  background-position: 0 0.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
main.case-study section .details ul.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sub-head {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.25rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sub-head {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="case-study">
  <section>
    <div class="details__top">
      <div class="details">
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6 class="kicker kicker--bold">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
          </h6>
          <h6>
            <span>Plan:</span>
            <span> <a href="#">Professional</a></span>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6>
            <span>Users:</span>
            <span>23</span>
          </h6>
          <h6>
            <span>Founded:</span>
            <span>2017</span>
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="details__detail">
          <h6>
            <span>Favorite Features:</span>
            <span>
              <a href="#">SMS</a>,
              <a href="#">Amazing Service</a>,
              <a href="#">Call Flows w/ Auto Attendants</a>,
              <a href="#">Auto-Attendant</a>
            </span>
          </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
    <section>
      <div class="details">
        <h4 class="sub-head">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A laudantium amet id? Harum eius magni iure veniam architecto expedita, commodi quidem ut voluptatem laborum sint? Possimus reprehenderit ullam tempora distinctio ea quos nisi aliquid, soluta dicta repellat ipsam velit officia doloribus, labore odio quis sit dolorum quibusdam earum. Iste unde voluptatibus ad necessitatibus quia recusandae voluptas asperiores quam, tempora ipsam?
        </h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, dolore omnis inventore laborum in sequi adipisci a alias nesciunt aliquid? Perferendis voluptates ipsa dicta fugiat!</p>
        
        <p>Cupiditate quam nisi non corrupti debitis fugiat excepturi? Perferendis, id dolor? Maxime molestiae voluptatibus ad, porro quidem sapiente pariatur cupiditate accusamus officia rem iste perspiciatis.</p>
        
        <p>Iusto, amet? Est eos, ducimus nostrum commodi, voluptate, ullam vero laboriosam dolores quisquam error sed exercitationem perspiciatis quia non soluta a facere mollitia quasi cumque?</p>
        
        <p>Cumque dolor doloribus obcaecati atque voluptatem temporibus eius sapiente, dolorum reprehenderit? Ea recusandae consequuntur similique quod hic? Id rerum architecto magni qui quis ratione totam.</p>
      </div>
    </section>  
</main>
```

Comment: It helps a little. The problem is it splits it 50/50. I'll have to work on it a bit, but I'm in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The desired result differs from the 50/50 suggestion simply because of the size of the sidebar.

Specify the logic for case-study:

```
display: flex
```

Then specify how big the sidebar should be:

```
section:first-child { width: 250px; }
```

(you should add classes to those section elements to target them easily:

`.sidebar` and `.content` could work

Then give the .content bit a `width` of `auto` or `calc(100% - 250px)` or whatever you need.